# Easiest way to store input into variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple form with options. I know there is a better way to store and parse the string to store it as a number.

```
<html>
<select id="values">
<option value="1"></option>
</select>
</html>
```

js:

```
var value = $('#values').parseInt(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.val()` to get the value first.

```
// + used to cast string to number
var value = +$('#values').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use;

```
   var value = parseInt($('#values').val(), 10);
```

[DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

**Summary**

The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix or base.
Syntax

```
parseInt(string, radix);
```